# Can't use shm_open after receiving from message queue

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue, shared-memory

I'm trying to implement a number of IPC methods in the same code using the following steps:

- 1 - Process1 opens a message queue and reads the message sent from Process2
- 2 - Process1 closes and unlinks the message queue
- 3 - Process1 writes something to a shared memory.

At step 3 any `shm_open()`, `memset()` or `memcpy()` system calls fail and Eclipse hangs in a new window that says "can't find a source file at ***" for whatever function I call.

When I disable the queue receive operation and just do the shared memory everything works fine.

So I'm suspecting that there is some unfinished business happening within the queue which is blocking any further calls from the process

Here is the problem in code: (just added the relevant part)

```
...

static int receiveFromQ(char *msgQName)
{
    int msgQFD;
    char buffer[33];

    /* Create and open the communication message queue */
    msgQFD = mq_open(msgQName, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0660, NULL);

    /* Read the message from the queue and store it in the reception buffer */
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    mq_receive(msgQFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL); // This is a blocking point until a message is received

    /* Use the data received ... */

    /* Close the queue */
    mq_close(msgQFD);

    /* Remove the message queue */
    mq_unlink(msgQName);

    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
       char *key = SM_KEY;
       int shmFD;

    /* Receive the data from the queue */
    int ret = receiveFromQ(MSGQ_NAME);

       /* Creates a shared memory object in a kernel space, with size = 0 */
    shmFD = shm_open(key, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0660); //The software stops here!
...
}
```

Instead of creating the shared memory, the software hangs at the `shm_open()` and claims that the source for the `shm_open` is not found.

Comment: The problem description seems inconsistent.  Does the `shm_open()` call *hang*, or does it fail? Only in the latter case would there be a basis for saying that it "claims that the source for the shm_open is not found."  Additionally how have you established that execution even reaches the `shm_open()` call?

Comment: Overall, you must be sure to check the return codes of all your method calls to catch failure codes and react appropriately.  This will give you a better idea of what's going on.  For us to help you more directly, however, we likely will need a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, which likely will include code for the other participating program.

Comment: when I debug the program it fails at shm_open and directs me to the "source not found" window. The shm_open function works fine if called before calling receiveFromQ().

Comment: I'm going to wildly guess that you're corrupting your stack in the `/*use the data received */`, so that the `shm_open` is now taking a value for `key` that is garbage. Your code as shown won't trigger that.

Comment: Here is the message I get upon calling shm_open(): Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-yWQXbR/glibc-2.24/rt/../sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c"

Comment: It's stopping because *something* is happening on the invocation of `shm_open`. It's important to find the *reason* for the stop. It's probably a SEGV (address invalid error) on the value in the `key` variable. The lack of source is just because it's in the C run-time that you don't have source for. Put in a breakpoint before the invocation of `shm_open` and verify that the `key` variable is sane. (Alternatively, put a write breakpoint on the address of the `key` variable and see when it trips.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Petesh, the problem was inside the /* use the data received */ part which I omitted from the code because I thought it is irrelevant! To clarify: in this part I made a mistake with the size of data copied using memcpy() which caused a buffer overflow. This did not show any error but somehow blocked further processing of the program.
Thank you all for the useful comments.

Answer (score -2):

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

This will set `buffer[0] = 0` because `sizeof(buffer) = sizeof(char*) = 1`.
Better idea are:

```
char buffer[33] = {0};
```

Or

```
#define BUFFER_LEN 33U
...
char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
...
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(char) * BUFFER_LEN);
```

Or

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]);
```

`sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]` calculate size of fixed array (non pointers allocate using malloc). So result will be 33.

Comment: This is not true. For `char buffer[33]`, then `sizeof(buffer)` is `sizeof(char[33])` is `sizeof(char) * 33` is `33`. The one of few exceptions from implicitly converting an array type to pointer to type is inside the `sizeof` expression.

Comment: I'm sure there's some funky embedded DSP or the like architecture where the size of a pointer is 1. OP is not using it. And the size of the buffer array is not the same as the size of a pointer to a char.

Comment: You seem to be confused Igor.  `sizeof(buffer)` is the sizeof of the variable buffer. The buffer variable is an array of 33 `char`s. So `sizoef(buffer)` is the size of 33 `char`s. Arrays (in most contexts) are implicitly converted to pointers in C language (this is most confusing for new programmers). So for example `sizeof(buffer + 1)` is `sizeof(char*)`. The `+ 1` makes `buffer` to be implicitly converted to the pointer to `char`. After the conversion the `+ 1` is not executed, the compiler needs just type resolution.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])` is the common mnemonic for count in an array. The type of `buffer` is `char[33]`, so `sizeof(buffer)` is `33 * sizeof(char)`. The type of `buffer[0]` is `char`, it is one `char`. So the `sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0])` is equal to  `sizeof(char[33]) / sizeof(char)` which is equal to `33 * sizeof(char) / sizeof(char)`. It just so happens that `sizeof(char)` is equal to 1, which is guaranteed by the standard. Using `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(char) * BUFFER_LEN);` is the same as `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)` or `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(char[33]))`

Comment: I believe this is not the problem since the function works fine and reads the received value correctly.